# Is refinement of a composition series a composition series?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was given it as an exercise to check whether every refinement of a composition series is a composition series or not?

I think it follows from the definition itself that every refinement of a composition series is a composition series.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: How do you define the refinement of a composition series?

Comment: Usually the notion of a composition series entails a requirement of maximality, so you wouldn't usually be able to refine it further.

Answer (score 2):

If you follow wikipedia's definition:

> "A subnormal series is a composition series if and only if it is of maximal length. That is, there are no additional subgroups which can be "inserted" into a composition series."

So if you have a composition series you can not have a strict refinement of it i.e. every refinement is the trivial refinement so we end with the same composition series with which we started.